# Rows Only Displaying first record in a group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I have a department group and want to display agents for that department under the group. I know in query it returns more than one agent per department. However, only the first agent returned from the query is returned under the department group. Report design looks like this:

[image]

How to get all the data to display?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to add a detail grouping to the row that displays the agents.  Should be a pretty simple fix.

1. Right click on the cell with [Cal_AgentNameId] and navigate to Add Group > Row Group > Parent Group.
2. Select the option for `Show detail data` and hit `OK`.
3. Right click on the group from the `Row Groups` near the bottom of the report builder and remove the sorting.

This should allow the query to display as many rows as are present in the dataset.  I didn't actually test this, so you may have to fiddle with it a bit. For example, you may need to select `Adjacent above` or `Adjacent below` when you add a new row group for it to allow a detail grouping.  If that's the case, you should be able to delete the extra row and keep the grouping.

Answer (score 0):

I just created Dummy Data for your requirement .Below screenshot of my Data

[image]

Now I have created a Detail Group as below

[image]

Then you Group by Department, In my Case "Group"

[image]

Results will be as below

[image]

You will get Extra Column as Group, You can delete that extra column.